# Attempting to run pip list from home directory

Tags: python, pip

When I run `pip list` I get `No such file or directory`. I am running it from the base / home directory.

```
cd ~

pip list
-bash: /Applications/Anaconda/anaconda3/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Is your conda environment active? Does the file actually exist? What does `type -a pip` say?

Comment: `-bash: type: pip: not found`. conda environment is not active.

Comment: So, if the conda environment isn't active, and you have no other pip installed, what were you expecting to happen? It sounds like you simply need to activate the conda env.

Comment: @wjandrea running `conda info --envs` throws an `Error Report`.  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'urllib3.exceptions'  `.  I have run `pip` commands before without any issues.

Comment: Sorry, how are you running `conda` if the environment isn't active? I'm not an expert on Anaconda.

Comment: I just noticed you never answered my question: Does the file actually exist?

Comment: @wjandrea I just realized that `pip` was somehow uninstalled and all my packages are missing, apps have stopped running on local env. I tried to upgrade `pandas` using `pip3` and `conda`. I had the environment up and running fine until then.